# how can I get prezto to open github using my default browser?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, prezto

I'm trying to run the command

```
git-hub-browse
```

but I keep getting the error

```
browser not set or set to a non-existent browser.
```

When I check my default browser:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

I see:

```
Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
```

how can I get prezto to open github using my default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like prezto is relying on `$BROWSER` environment variable. Try to set it:

```
export BROWSER=google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: that worked- thanks! in which file did that get saved?

Comment: It will be gone after you close terminal. You can put that line into `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile` to get it permanent.